# Apt-get, no sudoers file

Tags: apt, sudo

I am trying to install a module using apt-get.

For that I do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install
```

But I get the following error:

```
sudo: can't stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

I have been trying to Google the answer but can't find any solution to the problem.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` relies on a database of allowed users and actions in `/etc/sudoers`. This error occurs because this file does not exist, so `sudo` doesn't know who is authorized to do what.

You need to recreate `/etc/sudoers` with a valid configuration. Assuming you want to authorize users in group "sudo" to elevate to root, this would work (as root):

```
cat > /etc/sudoers << 'EOF'
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
EOF
```

If you can't get a root shell any other way, or your root password is disabled, perhaps the easiest way to do this is to reboot, set `init` to your shell, then reboot again. For example, with GRUB 2, hit <kbd>e</kbd> at the bootloader to edit your menu entry, add `init=/bin/bash` to your kernel parameters, press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot, and run the above command from the shell that appears.

Comment: I can't become root by typing su. it says 'authentication failure'. But I can create directories with 'sudo mkdir somedirectory' for instance and my password gets accepted then.

Comment: My favourite: sudo su -

Comment: @jofel You can't do `sudo foo` if `/etc/sudoers` is missing... also you should not be doing those, it screws with the environment. Use `sudo -i` or `sudo -s` as appropriate.

Comment: @ChrisDown Ok, my comment was not very clever (I deleted it). Why seems `sudo mkdir` work for Hermann Ingjaldsson if there is no `/etc/sudoers` file?